# Loop issue in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a loop in nodeJS where i need to handle results of sequelize query.
I think to have to use promise or other, because the code is executed only for the last record.

Code is:

```js
pages.forEach(function(page) {
    db.Page.findOne({attributes: ['html', 'template', 'permalink'], 
       where: { id: page.id } }).then(obj=> {
            html=obj.html;
            permalink=obj.permalink;
            template=obj.template;
            var variables=[];

            console.log("PERMALINK",permalink);  // FOLLOWING CODE IS RUN ONLY FOR THE LAST RECORD

            db.PageVariable.findAll({
                attributes: ['variable_name','variable_value'],
                raw:true,
                where: {id_page: page.id}
            }).then(function (items) {
                console.log("----------");
                //.......
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

How can the loop be modified to work correctly?

Comment: What's the desired result or output?   Too much code missing to see what you're trying to accomplish with the loop.

Comment: I need the code be executed for all records instead of only the last

Comment: It does execute for all of them.  Whatever you're trying to do to accumulate results is only accumulating one result so you HAVE to show us that code.  Right now, this question is unanswerable because there's not enough information about what result you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **await**(only works with **async** function) to wait for a promise to resolve or reject, see more [here](https://javascript.info/async-await):

You can use it something like follows:

```
async function doStuff(page) {

  let result = await //your db calls

  // "done!"
}

for (page of pages) {     
    // Do something
   await doStuff(page);
  }
```

**Note:**

1. Only use the loop with async/await when it is spacial/necessity situation.
2. If you want to execute something in sequence, you cannot use forEach indeed. Just use a modern for … of loop instead, in which await will work as expected.
3. If there is no need to run tasks in sequence then use built-in utility **Promise.all()** to run tasks in parallel.

See the below example how **promise.all()** works:

```
const tasks   = asyncThingsToDo.map(runTask); // Run all tasks in parallel.
const results = await Promise.all(tasks);     // Gather up the results.
results.forEach(x => console.log(x));         // Print them out on the console.
```

Comment: this is not answering the question, just showing how async-await works. Not to mention your using await inside a loop which is a big no-no...

Comment: @DanStarns , Thanks for the correction. Actually it is modern for .. of which will work as expected(Edited the same).

Comment: No this is still not effective, you should be using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `page` processing in a function that returns a promise, like this:

```js
const getPagePromise = page =>
  db.Page.findOne({
    attributes: ['html', 'template', 'permalink'],
    where: {
      id: page.id
    }
  }).then(obj => {
    html = obj.html;
    permalink = obj.permalink;
    template = obj.template;
    var variables = [];

    console.log("PERMALINK", permalink); // FOLLOWING CODE IS RUN ONLY FOR THE LAST RECORD

    return db.PageVariable.findAll({
      attributes: ['variable_name', 'variable_value'],
      raw: true,
      where: {
        id_page: page.id
      }
    }).then(function(items) {
      console.log("----------");
      //.......
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
});
```

Then `map` your `pages` array to an array of promises (like the ones defined previsouly), like this:

```js
const allPagesPromises = pages.map(getPagePromise);
```

Finally, use `Promise.all` to resolve/reject all the promises

```js
Promise.all(allPagesPromises)
  .then(allResults => { // Do stuff })
  .catch(err => { // Handle errors });
```

### Note

Consider avoiding excessive callbacks nesting, like when you process a page. Instead split the logic into small functions that return promises, this will make things easier to read/debug.